# Are files uploaded to Ubuntu One a single instance or are changes to that file also uploaded?

Tags: ubuntu-one, files, sync, android

If I upload a file to Ubuntu One that I constantly make changes to (ie a password tracking apps' storage file) are the changes to that file automatically tracked/uploaded when I sync from my Android device?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, changes to files in your Ubuntu One shared folders should be automatically updated.  If they do not appear to be updating check your Ubuntu One application, look for the "File Sync is up-to-date" in the upper-right corner and re-connect if necessary.